# How to create relation many to many 3 Model laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wonder how to create relation from 3 tables.

Here is my model structure:

User Model

```
class User extends Eloquent { 
    public function Posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    } 
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('comment');
    }
}


class Post extends Eloquent { 
    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('Comments');
    } 
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }    
}

class Comments extends Eloquent {  
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }
    public function Post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    } 
}
```

User can have many post, and each post has many comments from user.

I tried to grab all comments from post with user who posted the comment

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments()->get();
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    // here my code now to get the user
    $comment->user()->get()
}
```

The result:

```
[
       {
        id: "1",
        post_id: "1",
        user_id: "1", 
        reply_text: "Testing", 
       },...
]
```

I think it's not efficient at all.

How can I make this more simple like:

```
[
     {
        id: "1",
        post_id: "1",
        user_id: "1", 
        reply_text: "Testing", 
        user_post: {
            id: 1,
            name: "Edi vianika",
            profil_img: "l.jpg"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Have a look at the section about [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) in the documentation and see if that answers any of your questions.  You shouldn't need to use `$comment->user()->get()` with relationships.

Comment: Thanks @PhillSparks .. thats work to me `return Tweet::with('user')->get();` really helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correctly answered on comments by Phill, and as he says, you should user [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading).

```php
$post = Post::with('comments', 'comments.user')->find(1);
```

Then you can simply iterate like this:

```php
foreach ($post->comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->user->name . ' said: ' . $comment->title;
}
```

Just for clarity tho, I would suggest you to name your `$comment->user` relationship to `author` instead, it feels natural to type `$comment->author->name`. You could do so as:

```php
class Comments extends Eloquent {

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('user', 'user_id');
    }
}

// Remember to change eager loading to 'comments.author'
```